# En algoritmo Javascript el ciclo while se queda en un bucle infinito y la función no toma los valores desde el prompt

Tags: javascript, funciones, condiciones, while, prompt

En este código no se logra salir del bucle, ni tampoco trabajar con los datos que ingresa el usuario. Estimo que el problema estará en la condición del while y del if, pues son idénticas, pero también probé cambiando la misma dentro del parámetro del while y tampoco me funcionó, así como que no pude hacer que la función calculo toma los valores que el usuario introduce, pero no pude encontrar esos errores.

```js
let compraTotal = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese importe Total de la compra"));
let cuotas = 0;

while (cuotas != 3 && cuotas != 6 && cuotas != 12) {
  cuotas = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese cantidad de cuotas (3,6 o 12)."));

  if (cuotas != 3 && cuotas != 6 && cuotas != 12) {
    alert("ERROR: ingrese cuotas: 3, 6 o 12");
  } else {
    alert("ingresó " + " " + cuotas + " " + "cuotas");
    cuotas = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese cantidad de cuotas (3,6 o 12)."));
  }
}

let calculoCuotas = 0;

function calculo(compraTotal, cuotas) {
  let calculoCuotas = compraTotal / cuotas;
  return calculoCuotas;
}

let resultado = calculo(compraTotal, cuotas);
mostrar(resultado);
```

Comment: El uso de while en esa fragmento de codigo es innecesario.

Comment: Si sale, el único problema es que estas pidiendo 2 veces que ingrese la cantidad de cuotas. Si respondes bien las 2 veces, sale.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sólo debes quitar la línea dentro del else

```
cuotas = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese cantidad de cuotas (3,6 o 12)."));
```

## Snippet funcionando

```js
let compraTotal = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese importe Total de la compra"));
let cuotas = 0;

while (cuotas != 3 && cuotas != 6 && cuotas != 12) {
  cuotas = parseInt(prompt("Ingrese cantidad de cuotas (3,6 o 12)."));

  if (cuotas != 3 && cuotas != 6 && cuotas != 12) {
    alert("ERROR: ingrese cuotas: 3, 6 o 12");
  } else {
    alert("ingresó " + " " + cuotas + " " + "cuotas");
  }
}

let calculoCuotas = 0;

function calculo(compraTotal, cuotas) {
  let calculoCuotas = compraTotal / cuotas;
  return calculoCuotas;
}

let resultado = calculo(compraTotal, cuotas);
console.log(resultado);
alert(`${cuotas} cuotas de ${resultado}`);
```